# Exception specification when overriding a virtual function?

Tags: c++

If a class inherits from another and overrides a virtual function, how must the exception-specification for the derived (overridden) function be related to the base function?

Is that is must be at least as restrictive? right? or others?

Comment: Note: Exception specifications are generally considered a bad idea and a failed experiment in C++ (Note: They are considered a failure for completely different reason than Java). IMO only "no throw" specifications are useful and you can't get more restrictive than that.

Comment: what do you mean @Martin? could you explain more?

Comment: @Josh Morrison: If code *does* throw something the exception specification doesn't allow, the program immediately aborts. This is about equivalent to curing somebody's acne by cutting off their head.

Comment: @Josh: check this out...An example of why Exceptions are a failed experiment.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828748/a-doubt-about-exceptionsgive

Comment: @Jerry Coffin Exception specifications should be considered in the same light as an assert of a post-condition.  If the code doesn't meet its post-condition, you want it to abort.

Comment: @Josh Morrison: I would consider them a failed experiment as they have been deprecated in the next version of the standard. See [Hurb Sutters Report](http://herbsutter.com/2010/03/13/trip-report-march-2010-iso-c-standards-meeting/). For broader read check his [blog about the subject back in 2002](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill22.htm)

Comment: @James Kanze: I would prefer my code to abort at `compile time` for contract violations in the interface. I rarely want my application to abort at runtime because of an exception (though I may want it to unroll the stack and exit).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, it must be at least as restrictive (§15.4/3):

> If a virtual function has an exception-specification, all declarations, including the definition, of any function
>   that overrides that virtual function in any derived class shall only allow exceptions that are allowed by the
>   exception-specification of the base class virtual function.

Comment: Just wondering from which site do you get these statements regarding C++, or is it from book?

Comment: Oops -- I forgot to include the citation. That's from paragraph 15.4/3 of the C++ standard.

Answer (score 4):

It is $15.4 p.5 in http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf:
"If a virtual function has an exception-specification, all declarations, including the definition, of any function that overrides that virtual function in any derived class shall only allow exceptions that are allowed by the
exception-specification of the base class virtual function"